# VBA loop one cell upward until cell not equal "" and a cell incorporate two IF functions

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I'm totally new to VBA, am learning it by myself. Here is the problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbSOW.png)

So for Column E
If B = "S" Then
E = ""  // null

If B = "F" Then
E = (Reverse Rank x **PREVIOUS** Adjusted Rank + no of failure + 1)/(Reverse Rank + 1)

or in formula excel format

E5 = ((D5*E4)+($K$1+1))/(D5+1)

So the problem lies on the PREVIOUS adjusted rank in the formula. Say, to get value of E5 it needs value of E4 BUT if E4 = "" so it has to go one cell upward. If one cell upward is also ="", it has to go one cell upward again until is not equal <> "".

The problem is I'm not sure what function is right to use. I think it would be IF and LOOP but I don't understand how to write the condition. Like I said I'm totally new and time constraints cause me anxiety.  Also, if you notice, for Column E there are two IFs function I suppose? One is E is depended on Column B.

If Range("B2:B" & lastRow) = "S" or "F" and one is if E="" or <> ""

How I incorporated with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this without using VBA. You can use the following to get the previous non-blank value in column E:

```
E5=INDEX($E:$E,MAX(ROW($E$1:$E4)*(LEN($E$1:$E4)>0)))
```

This formula looks in column E above cell E5 (i.e. E1:E4) and returns the one cell with the largest row value that is also not blank (length > 0).

From there, your whole formula becomes:

```
E5=IF($B5="S","",IF($B5="F",($D5*INDEX($E:$E,MAX(ROW($E$1:$E4)*(LEN($E$1:$E4)>0)))+($K$1+1))/($D5+1)))
```

Note that these are array formulas, so they must be validated using Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Also, the top non-blank value in column E has to be input manually or with a different formula.

Comment: Thank youx100! Will try this! Yes the top column E I have put some value. Thank you so much

Comment: Btw, I don't want the max value between E1:E4, I just need the value above empty cell. As long as it is not zero, then the value above cell is accepted. If that's the case I just have to delete 'MAX(ROW($E$1:$E4)' ?

Comment: It's not finding the max value, it's finding the value in the max **row** that is non-blank, that is the last non-blank value in that column.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot! I got it now! You have been a great help!!

Answer (score 0):

1. What's the first value in column E when you meet the first "F" in
   column B? I mean, there is nothing in column E, what is the "PREVIOUS Adjusted Rank". In this case, I just set it 0.
2. What's  "no of failure"?

Here is my solution for you and I set "no of failure" as zero.

```
Sub test()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim previous As Single
Dim NoOfFailure As Single
For i = 2 To Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "S" Then
        Cells(i, 5).Value = ""
    ElseIf Cells(i, 2).Value = "F" Then
        previous = 0
        NoOfFailure = 0
        For j = i To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(j, 5).Value <> "" Then
                previous = Cells(j, 5).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Cells(i, 5).Value = (Cells(i, 4).Value * previous + NoOfFailure + 1) / (Cells(i, 4).Value + 1)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry for unclear description. First column in E when B=F is equal to 1.
No of failure is in cell K1, which is input by user.
Thank you so much for answering! Help me a lot!!

Comment: Thank you everyone who helps me! I already got the answer!! Thanks so much!! This is an awesome community!